# setting variables to inlines with variables in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set the value of a variable to one line of a file, over and over.

```
for i in {1..5}
   do
       THIS = "grep -m $i'[a-z]' newdict2" | tail -1
       echo $THIS
   done
```

What's the trick to this black magic?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Also, the line should be `THIS=$(grep -m $i'[a-z]' newdict2" | tail -1)`

Comment: Also note that there cannot be spaces on either side of the equals sign in an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easier to run it with sed than tail and grep's -m option:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    THIS=$(grep -e '[a-z]' newdict2 | sed -ne "${i}p")
    echo "$THIS"
done
```

If you start from 1 to x, other ways to solve it is through line reading in a loop:

```
while IFS= read -r THIS; do
    echo "$THIS"
done < <(grep -e '[a-z]' newdict2)
```

And through awk:

```
while IFS= read -r THIS; do
    echo "$THIS"
done < (awk '/[a-z]/ && ++i <= 5' newdict2)
```

Another awk version with different initial value:

```
while IFS= read -r THIS; do
    echo "$THIS"
done < (awk 'BEGIN { i = 2 } /[a-z]/ && i++ <= 5' newdict2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to find the occurrences once, and loop over them.

```
grep -m "$i" '[a-z]' newdict |
nl |
while read i THIS; do
    echo "$THIS"
done
```

If you don't need `$i` for anything inside the loop, remove `nl` and just `read THIS`.

Note also the use of double quotes around variable interpolations.

Comment: In a pipe, normally the THIS variable would be lost after the loop but in bash there's a way to run the last non-external command in the current shell by disabling job control (`set +o monitor`) and enabling lastpipe (`shopt -s lastpipe`). Another way for this of course is to use process substitution.